# Optimizing 4 sorted sets

Tags: optimization, memory-management, data-structures, redis, sortedlist

I'm currently using Redis as a time sorted index for my Mongo database. My mongo document looks something like this:

```
{ 
    _id : MongoId,
    title : "Title",
    publishDate : new Date().getTime(),
    attachments : [
        { 
            title : "Title",
            type : "VIDEO"
        },
        { 
            title : "Title",
            type : "PHOTO"
        },
        { 
            title : "Title",
            type : "LINK"
        }
    ]
}
```

Attachments can have 0 to 3 items in it. (No attachment, only link / only video / only photo, 2 of different types, 3 of different types)

Each time a document is added to Mongo it's automatically added to a sorted set in Redis.
The publishDate (unix timestamp) is used as the score and MongoId is used as the sorted set member. The key has the name "monitor:latest:feed"

If the attachments array contains a link, I add the same member to a sorted list with the key "monitor:latest:feed:links". Same goes for videos/photos.

The result is I have 4 Redis lists that are sorted by time. 
The lists are called:

- "monitor:latest:feed" that contains all of the document ids in mongodb.
- "monitor:latest:feed:links" contains all the document ids that have an attachment with the type link.
- "monitor:latest:feed:photos" contains all the document ids that have an attachment with the type photo.
- "monitor:latest:feed:video" contains all the document ids that have an attachment with the type video.

Is there a way I could remove the last 3 sorted sets or use some other data structure that takes less memory in Redis? Keeping in mind that I would still need the members sorted by time somehow.

Comment: You could use hashes to stock documents with their ids included in the key. Then you just use the key as value in you zsets. It will consume less space as one document is not duplicated through memory, but you will have to do much more queries to read data (zrange + n read from hash for instance) and will have to clean regularly and manually unused hashes (with ttl for instance).

Comment: One document isn't duplicated in multiple lists. I only store the document id (a 12 byte string). I updated my question on that point also.

Comment: You can define a special value for your zset "monitor:latest:feed" with the document id + links + photos + videos. Of course, if you are looking for a range based on photos for instance you will have to iterate through the zset to append enough values (till the end, in a bad case) as you can't get natively the rankings. But if you have a lot of data that is almost homogeneous, that you don't look for a big range, it can be an alternative to consume less memory. This is the tradeoff: runtime perf vs memory space. If you just stock the id as value in zsets it should be quite small however.